# How do you use a dynamic query in a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fixed query on which I can add only new columns, let's say this:

```
SELECT '1', '2' , 'Place I can insert my subquery1', 'Place I can insert my subquery1'
FROM FixedQueryTable
```

I also have a table with a column that stores some values and another that stores the name of the columns from which I have to get the other values.

```
TABLE1
----------------------------
ValuesColumn | NameColumn
_________________________
Val1  | Col1
Val2  | Col2
Val3  | Col3

Table2
----------------------------
Col1|Col2|Col3
______________
Val4|Val5|Val6
```

Now, what I want to return is

```
1|2|Val1Val4|Val2Val5|Val3Val6
```

I've written this

```
declare @qry nvarchar(max) = 
'SELECT top 1 ' + 
        STUFF((
                SELECT ', ' +''''+ ValueColumn +'''+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR,' +NameColumn +') ' 
                FROM Table1 
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')  + ' FROM Table2'
select @qry
execute sp_executesql @qry
```

And it works great as a stand alone, but I cannot use it to return the result from a function and I cannot use it directly as subquery (declare, exec, etc... obviously)
Do you guy know what I could do?

Comment: A query is *either* uses dynamic SQL or it does not.  There is no "dynamic SQL" subquery in SQL.

Comment: The root of the problem is your design. When you start storing column names in a table so you know what column to query things have gone the wrong way.